# The session is not working properly in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, laravel

The session is not working properly in PHP. The login page is working fine. But after redirecting to my home page I couldn't able to see my login details it throws this error`Notice : Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\final\header.php on line`

and if I use the if-else state to hide my login/signup button it's not working. So please someone help me with this issue

My Login page

> ```
> <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/auth.css">
> <body>
>
>     <div class="login-box">   <h2>Login</h2>   <form action="handleLogin.php" method="post">
> <div class="user-box">
>   <input type="text" name="loginEmail" required="">
>   <label>Email</label>
> </div>
> <div class="user-box">
>   <input type="password" name="loginPass" required="">
>   <label>Password</label>
> </div>
> <a href="#">
>   <span></span>
>   <span></span>
>   <span></span>
>   <span></span>
>   <input type="submit" value="LogIn" name="submit">
> </a><br>
>
>
> <a class="nav_btn" href="signup.php"><i class="icon_profile"></i>Create New Account</a>   </form> </div>
> </body> </html>
> ```

LoginHandle page

> ```
>     <div class="login-box">   <h2>Login</h2>   <form action="handleLogin.php" method="post">
> <div class="user-box">
>   <input type="text" name="loginEmail" required="">
>   <label>Email</label>
> </div>
> <div class="user-box">
>   <input type="password" name="loginPass" required="">
>   <label>Password</label>
> </div>
> <a href="#">
>   <span></span>
>   <span></span>
>   <span></span>
>   <span></span>
>   <input type="submit" value="LogIn" name="submit">
> </a><br>
>
>
> <a class="nav_btn" href="signup.php"><i class="icon_profile"></i>Create New Account</a>   </form> </div>
> </body> </html>
> ```

My header session

```
  echo ' <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" >
      <p class="text-light my-0 mx-2">Welcome'.$_SESSION["username"].' </p> 
</form>';
```

Comment: Check that you either have session.auto_start = 1 in your php config, or you are calling session_start() in your code prior to rending the page. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Comment: You are only sharing the **HTML** part of your project which no value to question reader. You have to show how are handling the login and session setup! Also share formatted code. Also why is Laravel + CSS + JS tagged here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use the post method for the form and then store the values in the sessions but remember to start session first
Here you logged in

```html
<php? 
  // Check to see if we have some POST data, if we do process it
  if ( isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['pass']) ) {
    $_SESSION["name"] = htmlentities($_POST["email"]);
     header( 'Location: view.php' ) ;
     return;
  }
?>


<form action="handleLogin.php" method="post">
  <div class="user-box">
    <input type="text" name="loginEmail" required="">
    <label>Email</label>
  </div>
  <div class="user-box">
    <input type="password" pass="loginPass" required="">
    <label>Password</label>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="LogIn" name="submit">
</form>
```